# escape character using indexOf()

Tags: java, escaping, character

I'm reading a file line by line into sting and split it into smaller strings using `line.indexOf('"', 1)` and `substring()` 
but this way doesn't detect whether before `"` is `\` or not so it doesn't react to escape char. how do I solve this?

(I cannot just use `line.split('"')` couse `"` are both at beginning and ending of substring, nor split by other char, cause my task does not allow so.)

the whole reading segment is:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        while(line.length()>0){
            if(line.charAt(0) == ',' || line.charAt(0) == ' '){
                line = line.substring(1);
            }
            else{
                if(line.indexOf(',') != -1){
                    if (line.charAt(0) == '"'){
                    pabaiga = line.indexOf("\"", 1);
                    zodis = line.substring(0, pabaiga+1);
                    line = line.substring(pabaiga+1);
                    duomenys.add(zodis);
                    }
                    else{
                        pabaiga = line.indexOf(',');
                        zodis = line.substring(0, pabaiga);
                        line = line.substring(pabaiga);
                        duomenys.add(zodis);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    zodis = line;
                    line = line.substring(line.length());
                    duomenys.add(zodis);
                }
            }
            for(String elem : duomenys){
            System.out.println(elem);
            }
duomenys.removeAll(duomenys);
        }
```

I was not allowed to split only by , separator as there could be one in the middle of the string, using \, in text file was not an option. So I was suggested to determine one sting element as " text" but if it contains another " or \" in the middle, my current code doesnt work.

if my line from text file is `"start \"title\" end", 10, 20, "text"`
the sting array should contain

- [0] `"start "title" end"`
- [1] `10`
- [2] `20`
- [3] `"text"`

Comment: Please provide an example of the input. I imagine you can you `split` as it takes a regex.

Comment: Use a regular expression to solve your problem. You can define a regular expression negation that only matches when the preceding character is not a backslash (\)

Comment: Please [[edit]] your question with few examples of input and expected output because now your question is not very clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you use one backslash to escape another?  If so, you would actually want to look for the first double quote that's preceded by an even number of backslashes.  Please clarify whether this is what you require.

Comment: @DavidWallace yes, i want to find the first double quote without \ before it.

Comment: Is there any change that there will be comma inside [0] `"start \"title\" end"` part?

Comment: @user2542809 - I asked whether it was possible to use one backslash to escape another.  So, for example, if you have `"\\"""`, which double quote do you want to find?

Comment: I think the real answer here is **use a CSV parser**. Don't reinvent the wheel, especially is the wheel is deceptively complicated. [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You can first store your tokens in dynamic size component like `List`. To fill such list with your tokens you need to iterate over each character in your sentence and if it is not `,` that is inside quote then add it to tokenBuilder, but if that comma is outside quote then add current value of tokenBuilder to your tokenList. Here is example code.

```
String line = "\"start \\\"title\\\" end\", 10, 20, \"text\"";

List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder tokenBuilder = new StringBuilder();

boolean insideQuote = false;
char ch, prev = ' ';

for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
    ch = line.charAt(i);
    if (ch == '"' && prev != '\\') {// normal " (without \ before)
        insideQuote = !insideQuote; // starts or ends quotation
    }
    // commas that are outside quote or last character in line 
    // should invoke adding non-empty builder to list
    if (ch == ',' && !insideQuote || i == line.length() - 1) {
        if (tokenBuilder.length() > 0) {
            tokens.add(tokenBuilder.toString().trim());
            tokenBuilder.delete(0, tokenBuilder.capacity());
        }

    }
    // add every character to builder except \ that are inside
    // quotes and have " after it
    else if (!(ch == '\\' && i + 1 < line.length()
            && line.charAt(i + 1) == '"' && insideQuote)) {
        tokenBuilder.append(ch);
    }
    prev = ch;//in next loop previous character should be our current one
}

String[] array = tokens.toArray(new String[tokens.size()]);

for (String s : array)
    System.out.println(">" + s);
```

Output:

```
>"start "title" end"
>10
>20
>"text
```

Comment: that's the problem that where can be a comma in the middle of the string and it should be considered as part of the string if its between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this (online example at http://ideone.com/TTtlZV):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         boolean inQuoted = false;

        List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s = "\"start \\\"title\\\" end\", 10, 20, \"text\"";
        StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder();
        for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ){
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            char cPrev = ( i == 0 ? (char)0 : s.charAt(i-1));

            if( c == '"' && cPrev != '\\' ){
                inQuoted = !inQuoted;
            }

            if( c == ',' && !inQuoted ){
                if( current.length() > 0 ){
                    parts.add(current.toString());
                    current = new StringBuilder();
                }
            }
            else {
                int length = current.length();
                if( length > 1 && c == '"' && current.charAt(length-1) == '\\' ){
                    current.deleteCharAt(length-1);
                }
                current.append(c);
            }
        }
        if( current.length() > 0 ){
            parts.add(current.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(parts);
    }
}
```

It won't handle double escaping. For example

> \\"

If I run this program the output is:

> ["start \"title\" end",  10,  20,  "text"]

Answer (score -1):

If you want the last index then just use lastindexof

```
.lastindexOf("\"", 1)
```

Just replace

```
pabaiga = line.indexOf("\"", 1);
```

with

```
pabaiga = line.lastindexOf("\"", 1);
```

Comment: The OP wants to find the index for the first `"` **not preceded by** `\\`. I.e. the first _unescaped_ quote. This doesn't solve that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think he is looking for the second " so that he can find the end of the line. Correct me if i'm wrong OP

Comment: Boris the Spider said just what i wanted, I edited my question, maybe it is more cleare now

Comment: Next time consider using an example to illustrate your point.

Comment: @BoristheSpider .lastindexOf("\"", 1) will get you the last index of " in the string

Comment: my substring is not neccesserely the only one i should get, in example i neen Name, Lastname, age, info. your suggestion would copy everything from begining of Name to end of info to one substring